# How to edit wpfdatagrid other cells while one of it's cell is invalid?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, wpfdatagrid

In `WPF datagrid`,When a cell is invalid,it prevents the the other cells editing so user can not enter data until the invalid cell comes valid.I was wonder if there is a way to disable this behavior?

There is how i use `datagrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ..}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
         Binding="{Binding Name
         , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
         , NotifyOnValidationError=True
         , ValidatesOnDataErrors=True
         , ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overrided the OnCanExecuteBeginEdit method of the `datagrid` like below and it works now.

```
  protected override void OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hasCellValidationError = false;
        var hasRowValidationError = false;
        const BindingFlags bindingFlags =
            BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var cellError= this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasCellValidationError", bindingFlags);
        var rowError = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasRowValidationError", bindingFlags);

        if (cellError != null) 
            hasCellValidationError = (bool) cellErrorInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        if (rowError != null)
            hasRowValidationError = (bool) rowErrorInfo.GetValue(this, null);

        base.OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(e);
        if ((!e.CanExecute && hasCellValidationError) || (!e.CanExecute && hasRowValidationError))
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

the same question:[DataGrid: On cell validation error other row cells are uneditable/Readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093074/datagrid-on-cell-validation-error-other-row-cells-are-uneditable-readonly)

Answer (score 1):

If it is an mvvm application and this behavior will repeat multiple times in your application, 
you can create your own `DataGrid` that inherits from `DataGrid`, and override the `OnCellEditEnding` method like this:

```
public class myDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

If not, you can do the same by registrating to the `CellEditEnding` event of your grid, something like this:

```
            mainGrid.CellEditEnding += (s, e) =>
                                       {
                                           e.Cancel = true;
                                       };
```

Comment: Thanks Omribitan but there is a problem with this answer.If i set e.Cancel=true,`DataGrid` will remain in edit mode after user leaves the `TexBox` inside `DatagridTextColumn`,and it causes many problems later.

Comment: @raha as I understood your question, you were looking for a way to stop the datagrid from preventing you to enter edit mode in other cells, when you entered an invalid value to a cell. have I misunderstood? are you now looking for something else?

Comment: No,The question is still the same,but as i said in my previous comment i can't use your solution because it causes other problems on datagrid.in my last comment i mentioned that problem.

Comment: for example i get this error sometimes:"'Sorting' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction."(When user leave the `textbox` after editing that,`datagrid` should get committed,but it doesn't because i overrided the `OnCellEditEnding` method and set `e.Cancel = true`)