# Frozen rows in WPF Datagrid when using CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with five columns: First name, Last name, User, Password and Role. I used CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate only with Password and Role. The thing is that after I enter editing mode on a cell that belongs to one of the columns named Password or Role, I can't enter editing mode for the other rows except the one that contains the respective cell. 
I don't know what to do anymore, I've lost two days already.

Here is my code:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          IsReadOnly="False"
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}"
          RowHeight="30">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <continut:UtilizatorRowValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"></continut:UtilizatorRowValidationRule>
    </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="CornflowerBlue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!--First Name-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                Header="FirstNume"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--Last Name-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                Header="LastName"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--User-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                Header="User"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--Password-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                Header="Password"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterCellStyle}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Click here to modify."></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <PasswordBox Name="PasswordBoxPass"
                                 PasswordChanged="PasswordBoxPass_PasswordChanged"
                                 Width="300"
                                 Height="25" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--Role-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Role"
                                Width="*"
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterCellStyle}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Select the role."></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2"
                              Grid.Column="2"
                              IsEditable="False"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.RoleVM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenRole, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              Height="25">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                                           Width="300"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Is it possible that some of the styles that I have applied may cause this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you can edit them at all? Because I see that you provided `CellTemplate` for them, but there's no `CellEditTemplate`. Also, if you're using just plain `TextBlock` elements, then it's easier to just use `DataGridTextColumn`.

Comment: I used CellEditingTemplate only for Password and Role. Could that be a problem?

Comment: I think your problem comes from the row validation rule you use. I just stumbled upon an issue that is quite similar to yours: when I edit a cell of a row that has a validation error, all the other rows become "locked", I can no longer edit them until I fix the validation error on the row I was editing in the first place. FYI, it seems you can clear the validation by pressing Esc once or twice on the cell you are editing, thereby re-enabling the edition of the other rows, but in my case I wish to keep the validation error while still being able to modify the other rows. No solution yet though.

Comment: Questions related to what I was talking about: [DataGrid: On cell validation error other row cells are uneditable/Readonly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4093074/20984) and [How to edit wpfdatagrid other cells while one of it's cell is invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18810009/20984)