# Datagrid cell background error after changing validation error behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to move next cell to edit although there is an validation error. I've used following code.

```
protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Referred Article - [edit wpfdatagrid other cells while one of it's cell is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810009/how-to-edit-wpfdatagrid-other-cells-while-one-of-its-cell-is-invalid)

It works fine, but when I add a background row color to it, the color disappears when editing
[image: As in the image]

Comment: What does the code snippet have to do with the background color of the row? It's not clear to me what you are asking. It would be great if you could clarify this

Comment: The code snippet does is enabling the editing of cells whether some cells have validations errors like above in the image.So the code is doing the job.But the issue is when the code executes background color is changing to white.I need to remain the color same as yellow after skipping the cells

Comment: But there is a issue all data is reset

Comment: This is because the cells stay in edit mode (that has white as default background color). Try to figure out how to change the editing-background. (I can't at the moment because I don't have a PC in range)

Comment: If we use e.cancel = true; How to check there is a validation error or not using code behind ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a different Style for cells that are in edit mode. Because you cancel escaping the edit mode by the code you've shown, this style will always show as soon as you started editing. Keep in mind, that the cells being in edit mode could also cause other problems. It would be better to change the behaviour of your code to only cancel the `CellEditEnding`-Event when there are validation errors.

To address the issue of the color change: DataGirdColumns have a `EditingElementStyle` that can be changed. To bind the Background of the `EditingElementStyle` (in this example of the `DataGridTextColumn` "Test") to the normal (not editing) Background use the following XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Test">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Then the background won't change when you edit a cell.

Comment: I tried this one but didn't worked. I declared it in a resource dictionery .So how to continue wuth this approach.                                          <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="EditingElementStyle" >
                <Setter Property="" Value="" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

Comment: your style should rather be somewhat like <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}"> <Setter Property="EditingElementStyle"><Setter.Value>--here the textbox-style that is shown in my answer---</Setter.Value></Setter></Style>.

Comment: But when i add it says, The member "background" is not recognized or is not accessible

Comment: The style is not applying