# How to continue working although a validation error in a DataGridCell occured?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datagridcell

I would like to display some values in a DataGrid. One column shall display integer values. When the user enters non-digit characters I want to tell this to the user but this value may be persisted though. 
Currently I am using a ValidationTemplate for a DataGridRow. The problem is that the complete row...the complete DataGrid is uneditable anymore until an integer value is entered in the particular cell.
How can I achieve it to inform the user that he entered a wrong vlaue but allow this in the end?

Here's the style I am currently using:

```
<Style x:Key="errorRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4,0,0,0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="!" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0]}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Update 2018-01-13:**

[DataGrid: On cell validation error other row cells are uneditable/Readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093074/datagrid-on-cell-validation-error-other-row-cells-are-uneditable-readonly)

is very close to my problem but it does not solve the problem that the entered (invalid) value ***is not*** put through to the `ObservableCollection` bound (twoway) to the cell with the invalid (alphanumeric) value (which is in fact a string property but the validator validates against an integer value) but a valid integer value is. (As I mentioned: the GUI is rather tolerant than restrict and shall give the user a hint and visualize that the entered value does not meet the requirements but even this invalid value shall be accepted.)

Can the validator be the reason??

```
namespace ConfigTool.Tools
{
    public class CycleValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            //DataRowView dataRowView = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as DataRowView;
            //string no = Convert.ToString(dataRowView.Row[0]);

            if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int i))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false,
                    "Cycle should be an integer value.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGrid: On cell validation error other row cells are uneditable/Readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093074/datagrid-on-cell-validation-error-other-row-cells-are-uneditable-readonly)

Comment: Basically yes, but see my edited question: Although cell represents a string value, only integers are stored in the bound ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#errorinfo)
helped me to find a solution.

I changed my ValidationRule class as follows:

```
public class CycleValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup group = (BindingGroup)value;
        StringBuilder error = null;
        foreach (var item in group.Items)
        {
            IDataErrorInfo info = item as IDataErrorInfo;
            if (info != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.Error))
                {
                    if (error == null)
                    {
                        error = new StringBuilder();
                    }
                    error.Append((error.Length != 0 ? ", " : "") + info.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        if (error != null)
            return new ValidationResult(false, error.ToString());
        else
            return new ValidationResult(true, "");

    }
}
```

In the underlying entity class implement IDataErrorInfo this way (extract):

```
string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
            if (!int.TryParse(Cycle.ToString(), out int i))
            {
                error.Append("Cycle should be an integer value.");
            }

            return error.ToString();
        }
    }
```

In the XAML file I added

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <local:CycleValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

to the DataGrid.